# how to access protected method from other package in andorid

Tags: android, payment, protected

I am developing sample android application for payment gateway of EBS. I have imported their sdk into android project.

EBS sdk provided one Getter and Setter class namely "PaymentRequest" Class
and we have to set all values to setter method of "PaymentRequest" Class.

But i want to set secure hash key to one method but that method is protected in PaymentRequest class. and also that class has private constructor . so how can i set secure hash key to protected method

```
protected String getSecureKeyHash() {
        return this.secureKeyHash;
    }

protected void setSecureKeyHash(String secureKeyHash) {
    this.secureKeyHash = secureKeyHash;
}
```

How to access these method from myActivity,

```
PaymentRequest.getInstance().setSecureKeyHash("sdf");
```

But setSecureKeyHash is not Accessible

Comment: Either you use reflection or you Subclass the PaymentRequest-class. But is this really the way to go with their SDK? Maybe there is a good reason, why this method is protected? Have you asked their support?

Comment: i have asked support but not replayed yet

Answer (score 0):

```
PaymentRequest mPaymentRequest = PaymentRequest.getInstance(); 
 Class c = mPaymentRequest.getClass();
        try {
            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("setSecureKeyHash",String.class);
            method.invoke(mPaymentRequest,"ur value");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Cannot access method: void com.ebs.android.sdk.PaymentRequest.setSecureKeyHash(java.lang.String)

Comment: Set the method accessible before invoking it: method.setAccessible(true)   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-

Comment: try what  Christopher said.i forget method.setAccessible(true),sorry.